# How to properly import between src and test modules

Tags: python

I have a project that I run from
`root_dir> python ./src/main_file.py`. When I want to test it, I use `root_dir> python -m pytest` and it will search for any files of the format `test*.py` or `*test.py`.

I have a file structure similar to the following:

```
root_dir
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main_file.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py 
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── file1_test.py
```

What I'm wanting to do is create a test file to test `file1.py`, but I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` for what I believe is the following reason and I'm not fully sure what the proper way to address it is.

In file1_test.py:

```
./file1_test.py/
import src.file1 as file1

def test_file1():
  <do stuff>
```

The problem occurs inside `file1.py`, where:

```
./file1.py/
import file2.py

<blah blah blah>
```

pytest fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'`. If I change file1.py to:

```
./file1.py/ (EDITED)
import src.file2.py

<blah blah blah>
```

then pytest will run successfully. However, if my main_file.py imports file1.py from within the same module (src),

```
./main_file.py/
import file1

<blah blah blah>
```

Then `python ./src/main_file.py` will fail with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.file2'` due to that change. Changing file1 back to the original will work for main_file.py, but not pytest, and I'm stuck in a loop.

I can't figure out what I should be doing differently to get the normal import structure of main_file.py and pytest to cooperate. Should I be changing the directory? Should main_file.py be outside of src? I think I would just run into a similar issue where if file1 is importing file2, the import path a file outside of src expects and one inside of src will expect are always going to conflict.

Comment: `import src.file2.py` is this typo? Also, what did you set in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: You need to either configure your sys.path, or use `import src.file1` If you rename `src` to something like `my_module` it would make more sense.

Comment: @tchar is right. In your file1_test.py, it has no way of knowing where file1 is or where src is. The src directory would need to be added to python path then you should use `import src.file1`

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do what you want.

1. Prefered way

```
root_dir
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main_file.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── file2.py 
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── file1_test.py
```

All files in `my_module` shoud import like

```py
from my_module.file1 import some_function
```

Then you don't need to do any hacks

2. Keepin `src` and assuming statements like

```py
from src.file1 import some_function
```

are not what you want you need to modify your tests like

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('src')
```

3. Not modifying src, not modifying tests: Run tests with

```
PYTHONPATH=path/to/src pytest
```